# React native function getting global scoped inside functional component

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

Why my functions inside the functional components are getting global?

file1.js:

```js
const Home = () => {
  sayHello = () => {
    console.log("Say Hello from Home")
  }
}

export default Home;
```

file2.js:

```js
const Settings = () => {
  sayHello()
}

export default Settings;
```

Why my `sayHello()` function is accessible in the Settings screen

Answer (score 1):

This is because you declared it globally (without a var/let/const) in front, so you attached it to global scope which is `window`:

```js
const Home= ()=>{
  sayHello=()=>{
    console.log("Say Hello from Home", this === window)
  }
}
  
Home()

console.log(sayHello())
```

Simply change it to `const sayHello = () => {}` to make it local to the scope.

Comment: thanks, @Dominic for the answer. 

if I declare the same 
sayHello() function inside my setting screen same as Home.

and calling  sayHello() from another file.  Which sayHello() function will be called?

Comment: If it's global then it will be whatever file's code is executed last which depends on the order of your imports (i.e. completely unreliable and shouldn't be done). The last executing one will overwrite the previous. No one uses globals in this way, if you want a shared global then put it in a file with var/let/const in front and export it.